# Fusion Charts Formatting data values

Tags: php, fusioncharts

I am wondering whether there is a way to format the fonts for my datavalues. I have two sets of data that I want to plot on the same graph but I want to format the data values differently.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your Question: Do you want to have different fonts for different datasets or do you want to have different number formatting (e.g. 1.00 vs 1) for those datasets. Maybe i didn't understand at all ? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the multi-series chart, you can specify the color attribute for each series in the dataset tag. Refer to http://www.fusioncharts.com/docs/ChartSS/MSColumn3D.html#Anchor15